# Assigning null and garbage collection in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Assume a Vector of Integers:

```
Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>();
v.add(14);
...
v.add(47);
..
```

Now I want to release the memory for this Vector. I am trying to figure out the difference between the following three statements FROM THE GARBAGE COLLECTION PERSPECTIVE.

Option 1:

```
v.clear(); /*This will iterate over each object reference contained in v and assign null to it.*/
v = null;
```

Option 2:

```
v = null;
```

Option 3:

```
v = new Vector<>(); /*Just to be clear, I understand this statement also assigns a new object to v. :)*/
```

It makes sense that options 2 and 3 are equivalent in terms of garbage collection, but I want to be sure. Can anyone help with the difference between the three?

Concretely: If using option 2 everything anyhow gets released why do I need clear?

Comment: Vectors is largely a legacy collection which was replaced by ArrayList in 1998.

Comment: You only need to clear() the collection if you plan to reuse e.g.  to reduce garbage

Comment: Option 4: *do absolutely nothing* works fine and v *still* gets garbage collected.  Java takes care of this for you, you don't have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All options are have the same result for the gc, option 1 would save the gc some time (at expense of your own of course). Because all objects referenced from the cleared object, they are not referenced anymore and become garbage even before collecting the first object.

If any object has zero references to it, it will be seen as garbage by the gc.
Even if two or more objects reference to eachother that will be detected by the gc.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any need for explicit memory deallocation in Java. Garbage collector does it automatically.

`gc()` frees the memory which has no references. `v = null` helps to say that it's  ready for garbage collection.